# Why is the 0-order Maxima so wide for a single slit diffraction pattern?

Tags: optics, diffraction, superposition

When looking at the graph of single or double slit diffraction graph, I noticed then for single slit the 0 ordered Maxima is twice as wide as compared to the other nth order Maxima. However, for double slit all of the constrtive interference are of the same width. How can this be explained?

Comment: This is a reasonable starting description:  https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-physics/chapter/27-5-single-slit-diffraction/